# Is there a magic method in python for when a class is being evaluated?

Tags: python

I have a mixin class that is supposed to be used as a interface only when it is used with other classes, for example:

```
class Mother():
  pass

class Child(Mother):
  pass

class Mixin():
  def __init__(self):
    assert isinstance(self, Mother), 'Mixin can only be used with Mother implementations'
    super().__init__()

class Implementation(Mixin, Child):
  pass

Implementation()
```

The above works, but only when `Implementation` is being instantiated, can I somehow have the above assert be evaluated on code execution?

This is important so that the application won't run if someone implemented a class wrongfully.

(I'm not sure I worded the title correctly)

Comment: it won't work even if "when Implementation is being instantiated" - it'll find the relation to `Mother` via `Child` class (at least on Python >= 3.4)

Comment: That's intended, edited the code to be more specific

Comment: So you want the `class` statement to raise the exception exception? That would require a change to `type.__new__`.

Comment: It's not really a mix-in if it's constrained to another type; whatever `Mixin` does should be folded into `Mother` directly.

Comment: @chepner Yeah I had a hint I wasn't doing it the right way, in the end of the day I want to be able to have different combinations of inherited classes, so I thought of this "modular" way instead of having a different class for each possible combination

Comment: That's fine, but you don't really have multiple combinations if the mix-in can only be combined with a single class. It would be cleaner to have `MotherWithMixin` be a subclass of `Mother`.

Comment: @chepner well in my actual context there are several mixins which can be combined togheter, but all require methods and attributes found in `Mother`. Since it wasn't the original scope of the question I didn't examplify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it won't work even if "when `Implementation` is being instantiated" - it'll find the relation to `Mother` class via `Child` class (`Implementation` inherits `Child` ---> `Child` inherits `Mother`),
thereby `isinstance(self, Mother)` treats `Implementation` as derived from `Mother` class due to inheritance chain (considered as `mro` (*method resolution order*))
use [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__) hook instead:

```
class Mother():
    pass    

class Child(Mother):
    pass    

class Mixin():
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        assert isinstance(cls, Mother), 'Mixin can only be used with Mother'
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)    

class Implementation(Mixin, Child):
    pass    

Implementation()
```

Throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ..., in __init_subclass__
    assert isinstance(cls, Mother), 'Mixin can only be used with Mother'
AssertionError: Mixin can only be used with Mother
```

---

But if you need to allow `Mixin` to be applied to `Mother` class and its subclasses - use `issubclass` call instead:

```
class Mixin():
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        assert issubclass(cls, Mother), 'Mixin can only be used with Mother and its subclasses'
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
```

The hook will be applied on class declaration phase (before potential instantiation)

Comment: But that's the expected result

Comment: @Mojimi, what do you mean? You meant `'Mixin can only be used with Mother AND its subclasses' ` ? (see additional `AND`)

Comment: Yes, it needs to be instance of Mother, that's what the code says, but it isn't the question anyways

Answer (score 1):

You can also use metaclass, it is powerful and can help you understand python class.

```py
class Mother():
    pass    

class Child(Mother):
    pass    


class Meta(type):
    def __new__(meta_cls, name, bases, dct):
        if name != "Mixin" and all([not issubclass(b, Mother) for b in bases]):
            raise Exception('Mixin can only be used with Mother')
        cls = super().__new__(meta_cls, name, bases, dct)
        return cls

class Mixin(metaclass=Meta):
    pass  

class Implementation(Mixin, Child):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks, was not aware of this